# how to extract only time from DATETIME column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to extract the time from each field for now what i get is:

if i use the following code:

```
$row["real_stime"] = $row["start_time"];
$row["real_etime"] = $row["end_time"];
```

i get this output:

```
"real_stime":"2015-11-18 07:18:00","real_etime":"2015-11-18 20:18:00"
```

and if i use this code:

```
$row["formated_start_time"] = date("H:i",$row["start_time"]);
$row["formated_end_time"] = date("H:i",$row["end_time"]);
```

i get this output:

```
"formated_start_time":"00:33","formated_end_time":"00:33"
```

the output that i need is:

```
07:18,20:18
```

Comment: I think you mean `date('H:i')`

Comment: still i get this output: ""formated_start_time":"00:33:35","formated_end_time":"00:33:35""

Comment: `date('H:i')` wont return the seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `H` for `24` hour format and `h` for `12` hour format

```
$row["formated_start_time"] = date("H:i",strtotime$row["start_time"]));
$row["formated_end_time"] = date("H:i",strtotime$row["end_time"]));
```

See this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp) for more information on formats

See [Demo Here](https://eval.in/471730)

Comment: please look i edit my code but still i get the wrong output

Comment: @matant what is the value of `$row["start_time"]` and `$row["end_time"]`

Comment: as you can see in my output above: "2015-11-18 07:18:00","2015-11-18 20:18:00"

Comment: Glad I could help you:)

Answer (score 0):

use [`date('H:i:s')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

this should be

```
date("G:i:s",$row["start_time"])
      ^
```

change to this

```
date("H:i:s",$row["start_time"]);
```

So final well-form code is

```
$row["formated_start_time"] = date("H:i:s",$row["start_time"]);
$row["formated_end_time"] = date("H:i:s",$row["end_time"]);
```

[image]

Comment: please look i edit my code but still i get the wrong output